# Removing regex in string character

Tags: java, selenium

```
docPreview('https://dms.careerbuilder.com/viewer?Token=348861ef265b476d9e689ce2b1174853&key=3e33e4c135b20938f278cd3dd39437c7e6065052281bd9ccba894d655b0460e5')
```

and I want to remove `docPreview('')` remains string is my URL.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: i use replaeAll function but it doesn't work

Comment: Post your tried code at least. You should try using a REGEX to achieve what you want.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your string is always between `docPreview('` and `')`, then you can efficiently substring it out as follows:

```java
String str = "docPreview('https://dms.careerbuilder.com/viewer?Token=348861ef265b476d9e689ce2b1174853&key=3e33e4c135b20938f278cd3dd39437c7e6065052281bd9ccba894d655b0460e5')";
System.out.println(str.substring("docPreview('".length(), str.length() - "')".length()));
```

Answer (score 1):

There are more ways how to achieve this:

Code examples:

```
package selenium;

public class Ankush {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String s = "docPreview('https://dms.careerbuilder.com/viewer?Token=348861ef265b476d9e689ce2b1174853&key=3e33e4c135b20938f278cd3dd39437c7e6065052281bd9ccba894d655b0460e5')";
        
        // split by ' into an array and take second array member
        String[] s1 = s.split("'");
        System.out.println(s1[1]);
        
        // replace or replaceAll with empty string
        String s2 = s.replace("docPreview('", "").replace("')", "");
        System.out.println(s2);
        
        // cut substring
        String s3 = s.substring(12, s.length() - 2);
        System.out.println(s3);
    }
    
}
```

Output:

```
https://dms.careerbuilder.com/viewer?Token=348861ef265b476d9e689ce2b1174853&key=3e33e4c135b20938f278cd3dd39437c7e6065052281bd9ccba894d655b0460e5
https://dms.careerbuilder.com/viewer?Token=348861ef265b476d9e689ce2b1174853&key=3e33e4c135b20938f278cd3dd39437c7e6065052281bd9ccba894d655b0460e5
https://dms.careerbuilder.com/viewer?Token=348861ef265b476d9e689ce2b1174853&key=3e33e4c135b20938f278cd3dd39437c7e6065052281bd9ccba894d655b0460e5
```